# shell escape is disabled

Tags: minted, texniccenter, shell-escape, pygments, ifplatform

I am trying to use `minted` for code highlighting. Now to use this package I need to enable shell escape. So I have set the compiler options as follows:

[image: latex shell escape in TeXnicCenter]

However, I am still getting the same error from `minted`:

```
Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.
```

Only this time there is a warning from `ifplatform`:

```
shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.
```

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

*Additional Information:*

- Tex distribution: TexLive 2016
- Editor: TeXnicCenter
- Platform: Windows 10
- Installed python 3.5 and `pygments` using `pip`. The `scripts` path is also set in `PATH` variable.

Comment: Try first the command from a DOS window and see if you get same error. This makes it easier to isolate the problem from the GUI.

Comment: Have you checked if it is an issue that shell escape is last. I'd have `"%vm"`  last

Comment: Thank you all for your comment. Executing pdflatex from cmd line run successfully. And also in TeXnicCenter I had changed the argument list as `-interaction=nonstopmode  -shell-escape "%wm"`, and that also worked in TeXnicCenter. If possible please post it as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the options for latex, the tex file goes last (AFAIK). So when specifying options for an editor know which will be the placeholder for the tex file, and make sure it comes last