# Kile: shell-escape doesn't work

Tags: pdftex, kile

I have added these packages:

```
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

When I save, I have the error: `Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag \usepackage`

So, I added `--shell-escape` as an option in the pdflatex configuration of Kile (Configure Kile > Tools > Compilation).

It still doesn't work and I get the exact same error. Why?

Comment: Did you put one or two dashes before 'shell-escape'?

Answer (score 3):

It should work see the clean run on the left. It is possible your quick build is not currently set to the compiler you changed. Here I had added it to my current default settings for PdfLaTeX but am about to remove with a simple delete. You can create a new tool with those settings, but I try to keep my system as close to default for next test.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Generally, tex documents are compiled using the syntex

> `tex [OPTION]... [TEXNAME[.tex]] [COMMANDS]`

where `tex` is the name of the compiler that accepts certain options (including `-shell-escape`) then the source file and any other inputs if required (`COMMANDS`). This sequence should be maintained while specifying the editor's options i.e. place the placeholder of the source (.tex) file at the end. I have elaborated this answer from [dalief](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316775/252632)'s answer. I have tried this for TexStudio and kile editors and followed the following steps.

> For kile go to Configure Kile > Tools > Bulid > PDFLatex.

I have chosen here PDFLatex, however, one can choose the compiler of his/her choice and then specify in the options filed.

> `-interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %source`

If it does not work then press `Restore Default Tools` button and perform the same process (for kile only). Similarly for TexStudio go to

> Options > Configure TexStudio > Commands > PDFLatex.

add the following text

> `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex`

Also, make sure that you have already installed pygments package

> `sudo apt-get install python-pygments`